# Why wp_send_json return null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Objective: make the button "Add to favorites" and the page with the map of selected goods.
My favorites post id stored in js-cookie array

```
liked = $.cookie("liked");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action : 'ids',
        id : liked
    },
    success: function (response) {
    console.log('AJAX response : ',response);
}
```

in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ids', 'ids_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ids', 'ids_function' );    

function ids_function() 
{
    $myArray = array($_REQUEST['id']); 
    wp_send_json( $myArray );

}
```

in the page with the map of selected goods i call finction `ids_function()` and page return `null`. But in console.log i see the need array. How to get it in my page?? TNX!

Comment: Can you post the code that generates `null` ? 
Such as `$('.mydiv').html ('response = ' + response);` and it outputs `response = null` ?

Comment: `<? ids_function();  ?>` this generates `null`. I need id's in php array.

Comment: How do you know it's null ? You said that it writes the contents to the console.log normally ?   
That function `wp_send_json()`  also calls `die() ` so it never returns in PHP.

Comment: im noob)) yes, in log all good. How can i get array in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to accomplish but, you could rewrite that function to also work when called from PHP.

```
function ids_function ($is_ajax = true) 
{
    $myArray = array($_REQUEST['id']); 
    if ($is_ajax)
    {
        # NOTE: it die()-s here (after outputting the JSON data)
        wp_send_json( $myArray );
    }
    return $myArray;
}
```

Then you can call it from PHP like this:

```
$myarray = ids_function (false);
```

Also consider that PHP and Javascript runs at different times...

Comment: $myarray = ids_function (false);
print_r($myarray); //return Array ( [0] => ) - not work

Comment: Try this: `echo '<pre>' . print_r ($_COOKIE, true) . '</pre>';` .  See if your data is there. Also try to print the contents of $_REQUEST. See if it is there. If it is in a cookie, it should be sent by the browser on page load.
Then you can read that data inside the ids_function (). For example `if (!$is_ajax) { /* read data from $_COOKIE or $_REQUEST */ } `

Comment: Thank u so much! `$_COOKIE` is all that i need! `$posts = get_posts($_COOKIE['liked']);` work fine!